# Remover clase "validate" de bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Estoy buscando la forma de remover el sombreado verde que aparece alrededor de los input's al dejar de posicionarme en él.
El input usuario debería terminar como el input Name.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                    //console.log(response);
                    //response == 3 ? alerta(3) : alerta(4);
                    if (response == 3) {
                        $('#ajaxUserInvalid').hide();
                        $('#userValid').show();
                        $('#iUser').removeClass('invalid').addClass(
                            'valid');
                        $("#iUser").focusout(function() {
                            $("#iUser").removeClass('valid');
                        });
```

Aquí es donde se "supone" que quiero remover la clase 'valid' con jquery, aunque realmente sé que no es la forma correcta (porque no me funciona), espero puedan ayudarme y retroalimentarme si me ven perdido. Gracias.

Comment: Estás utilizando Materialize?

Comment: Si es sólo el sombreado se lo podrías quitar desde css modificando la clase con una hoja de estilos adicional.

Comment: @JheymanMejia estoy usando mdbootstrap.